# How to use Python BS4 to access text within HTML <p> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So here is my HTML:

[image]

How can I go about accessing "A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date." specifically in beautifulsoup using "find_all" command?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/771848) 3. What is the input - what facts do you know and can use to find the element?

Comment: Honestly have no idea how to approach this

Comment: @jkung2314: start by reading the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation)

Comment: jkung2314, Please include the actual HTML instead of a picture, I'll gladly solve this issue for you and help you with decent tips and guidance.

Comment: put HTML as text, not screenshot, and then we can use it to create example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>
    <strong>123</strong>
    A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

p = soup.find('p')

text = list(p.children)[-1]

print(text.strip())
```

If you have more `<p>` inside

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>
    Other p-tag
</p>
<p>
    <strong>123</strong>
    A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

all_p = soup.find_all('p')


text = list(all_p[1].children)[-1]

print(text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this HTML came from the cisco.com site. If so, here's a direct answer to your question.

```
>>> url = 'https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog/b_syslog/syslogs10.html'
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
```

First I tried looking for the unadorned string. However, upon more careful examination of the page, I noticed some trailing blanks.

```
>>> near = soup.find_all(string='A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date')
>>> near
[]
```

Using a regex makes it possible to search for a string *with* trailing blanks in the source page.

```
>>> near = soup.find_all(string=bs4.re.compile('A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date'))
>>> near
['A CTS PAC is nearing its expiration date.\n\t ']
```